# Проблема с debug для python в Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition

Tags: python, отладка

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой запуска debug python в visual studio 2017 community. 
У меня есть два проекта на одном компьютере. Первый проект запускает debugger и работает корректно (virtual envirnoment python 3.6). 
Я создал второй проект отдельно с virtual envirnoment anaconda 5.2 
При установке breakpoint и запуске debug получаю ошибку (текст ниже). Сравнил настройки для debug двух проектов - они одинаковые. Кто сталкивался с подобной ошибкой и решил проблему, плиз отзовитесь.

```
No compatible code running
The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap


def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-t','--test', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():
    print('Test Test')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема совместимости debug с Anaconda 5.2. После удаления Anaconda и установки Virtual Envirnoment c Python 3.6 все заработало.